# If $f\colon X\to Y$ is an almost one-to-one continuous map from the connected space $X$ onto $Y$, then, is it a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

Let $X,Y$ be metrizable compact spaces, with $X$ connected, and $f\colon X \to Y$ a continuous function onto $Y$. Suppose $f$ is *almost one-to-one* in the following sense: there exists $Y' \subseteq Y$, a dense $G_\delta$, such that $\# f^{-1}(y) = 1$ for all $y \in Y'$. Then, **can happen that $Y\setminus Y'$ is dense in $Y$?**

I have this situation in another problem and it is hard for me to image a that $Y$ has both a dense set of point where $f$ has a unique preimage and a dense set of points where $f$ has two or more preimages.

Comment: "$Y\setminus Y'$ is either dense in $Y$ or empty". If it is empty, then $f$ is trivíally injective. You should omit this case because it only leads to irritation. What abou the case that $Y\setminus Y'$ is non-empty but not dense?

Comment: @PaulFrost The case in which $Y\setminus Y'$ is non-dense and non-empty don't occur in my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. For instance, let $X=\{(x,y)\setminus [0,1]^2:y\le D_M(x)\}$, where $D_M(x)$ is a [modified Dirichet function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletFunction.html) and $f$ be the projection of $X$, $(x,y)\mapsto x$.